# how I do that the files that I have on a CDN are private for a specific user?

Tags: file, security, cdn, privacy

the problem is the next, I have mi pdf a img files in a CDN (in this case Smartfile ) but, if some person take the url of the img  he can access it at any time, I want to avoid that this happen for the privacy of my users, if it is possible, how I could do it with a CDN (no matters what)?

PD: sorry for my english I'm still  learning